# Comparing One-Step vs. Two-Step Random Selection Methods in a Code Golf Challenge.

Tags: probability, random

**One-Step**

I'm reviewing answers to this [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/271383/find-the-odd-one-out/271470#271470) challenge. Here's a target cell marked by `X` that was chosen using `rand()*512` ([rand()](https://%5Brandom%5D%5B2%5D) in C) ensuring that each cell has an equal chance ($\frac{1}{512}$) of being chosen for modification.

```
....................X...........
................................
................................
................................
................................
................................
................................
................................
................................
................................
................................
................................
................................
................................
................................
................................
```

**Two-Step**

Another solution first picked a random row `rand()*16`, then a random cell within that row `rand()*32`.

## Question

Does using that Two-Step method to pick the target cell violate the rule that each cell has an equal chance ($\frac{1}{512}$) of being chosen for modification, but perhaps it's okay if the following is true?

P(target cell) = P(row) $\times$  P(cell in row) = $\frac{1}{16} \times \frac{1}{32} = \frac{1}{512}$

Comment: "Does using that method to pick the target cell violate the rule..." : if this is the sole question to be answered, why force the reader to read through all of the posting, and only get to the question at the end.  Why not drastically simplify the posting, eliminating all info un-needed to solve the question, and place the question near the front of the posting?  For what it's worth, the Two-Step process is valid, as long as rand()*16 and rand()*32 are independent of each other (i.e. selection of the first random number in no way affects the selection of the second random number).